# How can I know which version of pip package to install?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, ansible, ansible-lint

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, with Python 3.4.3. I want to install the latest version of `ansible-lint` that is supported on that Ubuntu version and with this Python version.

One of the dependencies of the `ansible-lint` package is `ansible`.

When I simply use `pip3 install ansible-lint` I install for me a version of `ansible` that is not supported - since if I run `ansible-lint --version` I get the following error:

`Ansible requires a minimum of Python2 version 2.6 or Python3 version 3.5. Current version: 3.4.3`.

So how can I make sure that `pip3` install the correct version with the correct versions of the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/dev_guide/developing_python3.html):

> Python-3.5 was chosen as a minimum because it is the earliest Python-3
>   version adopted as the default Python by a Long Term Support (LTS)
>   Linux distribution (in this case, Ubuntu-16.04). Previous LTS Linux
>   distributions shipped with a Python-2 version which users can rely
>   upon instead of the Python-3 version

Also specifically:

> However, if you happen to be testing Ansible code with Python-3.4 or
>   earlier, you will find that the byte string formatting here won’t
>   work. Upgrade to Python-3.5 to test.

In short it seems like no version of ansible is good on python 3.4 - you should upgrade to at least 3.5. If you don't want to change the system-wide version, look into creating virtual environments for this project.